# Error occuring in values.xml which is present in build folder

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having problems with android application android studio and already built. Try to change values in the values.xml App->Intermediates->res->debug->values->values.xml file located in the folder. Every time I make a change and compile the application changes are lost.

and also i know The "intermediates" folder contains files that are created during the build process, and should not be modified.

But there is no file named values present in App->src->main->res->values path.[image: Error occuring is shown in the image]

```
Style.xml
<resources>

<style name="Cropper.Widget.Drawer.Seperator" parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/drawer_text_padding</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/drawer_text_padding</item>
    <item name="android:background">#5FFF</item>
</style>

<style name="Cropper.Widget.Drawer.Title.TextView" parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/drawer_text_padding</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/drawer_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#8FFF</item>
</style>

<style name="Cropper.Widget.Drawer.Option.TextView" parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/drawer_text_padding</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/drawer_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are changing the values in debug code.
The path you are using is-> App->Intermediates->res->**debug**->values->values.xml

You have to make changes in the main files which is in the res/values/values.xml or string.xml.
The debug code is cached every time you build the project.
Clean the project and run Build.

Comment: But there is no problem in style.xml and i also uploaded the same. can you point out the error in style.xml

Comment: yes, but you are looking it in debug file...Whenever you build an apk a debug_apk is created. So, you have to check for the real files not the debug files.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can not change on Itermediates files , Try to make change on your `Style.xml` file.  Intermediates files are generated when we build our application, Generally we override the files with our code.

Try to edit on your Style.xml and After that > Build > Clean Project > Run

Comment: i checked style.xml and ids.xml and String.xml and colors.xml many times but there is not any typos error in them, i clean and rebuilt project and invalidated cache and restarted android studio (chipmunk), but unfortunately chipmunk shows error still as below: Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\Ali Hoseyni\AndroidStudioProjects\gps1\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@a9d1a0a.